# How do I attach a CSS dependency to my Shiny app with htmlDependency() and tagList() from htmltools

Tags: css, r, shiny, dependencies, htmltools

I'm trying to attach a custom css stylesheet to style my shiny app. However I haven't had much success. I know that there is many ways to do it, but according to chapter 4 of [Outstanding UI with Shiny](https://unleash-shiny.rinterface.com/htmltools-dependencies.html) (right after figure 4.3) the best way to do so seems to be with *htmlDependency()* and *tagList()*.

I have created my dependency as shown below:

```
css_dependency <- function() {
  htmlDependency(
    name = "css dep",
    version = "1.0",
    src = "./www",
    stylesheet = "styles.css"
  )
}
```

However I am not sure how to attach it and where to attach it. With my browser developer tool, I can see that most dependencies seems to be in the <head> tag. Should I attach it like that?

```
tagList(head, css_dependency())
```

Also, I am not quite sure where I should call the *tagList()* function. Would that be directly in ui?

I can't seem to find many information on that method so any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think `htmlDependency()` is designed to be use with package. It constructs path to the file using passed arguments, but I think it won't work if there is no package. I made some experiments and it looks like it locates library directory and constructs path using name, version etc. So it doesn't make sense (at least because version is included in the path) without package.

Let's now divide the answer if we have a package or not:

**1. A package.**

You are close, but I would:

```
css_dependency <- function() {
  htmlDependency(
    name = "css_dep",
    version = utils::packageVersion("name_of_your_package"),
    package = "name_of_your_package",
    src = "./www",
    stylesheet = "styles.css"
  )
}
```

Assuming `styles.css` file is inside `www` directory **and** `www` directory is inside `inst` directory (`inst` directory is use to *install* elements inside *as is* when package is installed by user), I have changed:

- space from name - replaced by `_` (just for safe);
- hard-coded version number - now the version number will be the same as package version number (for convenience);
- new argument added - package name;

And how to use it?

**`tagList()`** makes it possible to return (e.g. by a function) multiple tags - it is e.g. needed in modules, without `tagList()` the function would return only the last tag. The usage is:

```
library(shiny)

tagList(tags$h1("h1"), tags$h2("h2"))
```

And it returns:

```
<h1>h1</h1>
<h2>h2</h2>
```

i.e. both tags at once.

I'm talking about this, because your example (`tagList(head, css_dependency())`) is wrong, inside `tagList()` you need to use tags in the same way like in the `UI` part of app directly.

How to include dependency then? It will be just:

```
tags$head(css_dependency())
```

Because you are right that dependencies should be inside `head` tag. **And** there is no need to use `tagList()` directly in the `UI` part (use it if you need to return multiple tags by some function which will be used in the `UI` part)

**2. Not a package.**

We should use different approach than `htmlDependency()`. I would say:

```
tags$head(tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "path_to_the_file"))
```

`"path_to_the_file"` is:

- relative to the directory where is a root of the application (i.e. where `app.R` or `server.R` and `ui.R` lives), so if you made a directory `css/my_stylesheet.css`, then it will be: `tags$head(tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "css/my_stylesheet.css"))`;
- **however** if you - the same as in your example - put your `css` file in `www` directory and `www` directory will be in the same directory where is a root of the application (i.e. not in some subdirectories), then you won't include `www` in path, because `Shiny` is designed to detect `www` directory automatically as a directory where will be `css` and `js` files., so in this case if `my_stylesheet.css` will be in `www` directory, the path will be: `tags$head(tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "my_stylesheet.css"))`